# Why does my Create-React-App on Heroku have NODE_ENV=development?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, create-react-app

I want to use NODE_ENV in my Create-React-App as described in https://medium.com/@tacomanator/environments-with-create-react-app-7b645312c09d

But when I run it on Heroku, `process.env` reports `{ NODE_ENV: "development", PUBLIC_URL: "" }` - why? `NODE_ENV` is `production` in my Heroku dashboard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved it myself with the `create-react-app-buildpack` buildpack:

```
heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git
```

And then redeployed my app to Heroku.